# RegEx for replacing capture group content using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace

Have inputs.conf files in multiple directories that needs to match and parse each stanza and modify the index= to index=secure.
This are files type in inputs.conf and also do run the script to locate the inputs file in this dir (_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf) to modify the index

```
[monitor:///var/log/messages]
index=BDBD_np
sourcetype=syslog

[monitor:///var/log/cron]
index=NDNW_np
sourcetype=syslog

[monitor:///var/log/maillog]
index=BSKX_np
sourcetype=syslog

[monitor:///var/log/secure]
index=NDNDK_np
sourcetype=syslog

[monitor:///var/log/spooler]
index=DNWN_np
sourcetype=syslog

[monitor:///var/log/audit/audit.log]
index=XBJB_np
sourcetype=syslog


    sed -i -e 's/.*(?s)((\[monitor\:\/\/\/var\/log\/messages|secure\]).*?)(?:(?:\r*\n){2})' /index=secure *linux*/local/inputs.conf

############################
match each stanza and modify index name to index=windows
inputs file in this dir (_GWAS_pr_window_t1/local/inputs.conf)


    [WinEventLog://Application]
    checkpointInterval = 5
    current_only = 0
    disabled =0 
    start_from = oldest
    index = 

    [WinEventLog://Security]
    checkpointInterval = 5
    current_only = 0
    disabled =0 
    start_from = oldest
    index = 

    [WinEventLog://System]
    checkpointInterval = 5
    current_only = 0
    disabled =0 
    start_from = oldest
    index = 

    [WinEventLog://ForwardedEvents]
    checkpointInterval = 5
    current_only = 0
    disabled =0 
    start_from = oldest
    index = 

    [WinEventLog://Setup]
    checkpointInterval = 5
    current_only = 0
    disabled =0 
    start_from = oldest
    index = 

    sed -i -e 's/.*(?s)((\[WinEventLog:\/\/Application|Security|System|ForwardedEvents|Setup\]).*?)(?:(?:\r\n){2}) /index=window *window*/local/inputs.conf
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us clear input along with the output you expect to see.

Comment: This what i am expected but getting error with the output

[monitor:///var/log/messages]
sourcetype=linux
index=secure

[monitor:///var/log/secure]
sourcetype=linux
index=secure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sed which reads line by line, you might use perl with the [-0 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147438/perl-match-newline-in-0-mode). You could capture for example this part in group 1:

```
[monitor:///var/log/messages]
sourcetype=linux
index=
```

Followed by matching `power` afterwards.

Then in the replacement you could referer to group 1 and add secure `$1secure` so that will replace the matched power.

```
(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=)power
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MqBVFW/1)

```
perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=)power#$1secure#g' inputs.conf
```

Result:

```
[monitor:///var/log/messages]
sourcetype=linux
index=secure
```

**Update**

If you want to match any of the listed words from the comments and replace those with what comes after index, you could use 2 capturing groups:

```
perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit\.log)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1$2#g' inputs.conf
```

Pattern

```
(\[monitor:///var/log/(messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit\.log)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MqBVFW/4)

Result:

```
[monitor:///var/log/messages]
  sourcetype=linux
index=messages

[monitor:///var/log/secure]
  sourcetype=linux
index=secure
```

Comment: This is awesome but some of the stanza index name will not be power, it has over hundreds of different index name so 
how do i match each stanza that startwith [monitor:///var/log and endwith messages, secure, cron, spooler and audit.log]
and change the index name without modify any index name that do not reference to this stanzas 
[monitor:///var/log/messages|secure|cron|maillog|spooler|audit.log]
sourcetype=linux or whatever
index=whatever

Comment: @user10965163 Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/MqBVFW/2 or if the index name can not contain a space https://regex101.com/r/MqBVFW/3 or If you want to match one of the words and replace that with the value of index: https://regex101.com/r/MqBVFW/4

Comment: This are all the stanza i want to match and modify the index name and some of index name i don`t know so i want the script to match this stanza and change any type of index name it has

[monitor:///var/log/cron]
sourcetype=linux_secure
index=

[monitor:///var/log/secure]
sourcetype=linux_secure
index=power

[monitor:///var/log/messages]
sourcetype=linux
index=power

[monitor:///var/log/spooler]
sourcetype=syslog
index = linux

[monitor:///var/log/audit/audit.log]
sourcetype=syslog
index=

[monitor:///var/log/maillog]
sourcetype=syslog
index=

Comment: @user10965163 Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/KTUlut/1 Now you can match all the variants and use your own replacement.

Comment: Super great, so should it be like this

perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*$1secure_linux inputs.conf

Comment: Getting error with this, 

perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*$1secure_linux inputs.conf

Comment: perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1secure_linux#g' inputs.conf

Comment: Please all the directories is in this path: /tmp/apps$ and if i stand at the path and run the script it says  No such file or directory. how do achieve this 

perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1secure_linux_pr#g' *linux*/local/inputs.conf
perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1secure_linux_np#g' *linux*/local/inputs.conf

 _GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf 
 _GWAS_np_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf

Comment: I tested this on ubuntu an ran it from the same dir as where the file is: `perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1secure_linux_pr#g' inputs.conf`

Comment: the inputs.conf is in this dir 
deployment-apps# _GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf, _GWAS_np_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf so if run the script it say No such file or directory
 
deployment-apps# sed -E '/^\[/{h;b};G;s/^(index=)power\n.*(messages|secure)\]$/\1secure/;P;d' inputs.conf
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf 
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf

Comment: could not recorgnized dir path to inputs.conf

_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf 
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf 

perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1secure_linux_pr#g' *linux*/local/inputs.conf

Comment: In the comments you can format the code parts by using `backticks` to make it read a bit better. What is your os? Did you try running the code from the same dir as the file? You have perl installed right?

Comment: i have about 100s of apps in this dir <deployment-apps$> so i place the script at deployment-apps$ and run it and after i run, it says No such file or directory
 
like example of apps in deployment-apps$
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf 
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf

Comment: please how do i achieved this

Comment: The code works great with single file but file and directory not working for me, still getting errors:
perl -0p -i.bak -e 's#(\[monitor:///var/log/(?:messages|secure|cron|spooler|audit/audit\.log|maillog)\](?:(?:\R.*){2})index=).*#$1secure_linux_pr#g' *linux*/local/inputs.conf

Comment: Perhaps these pages  [page1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995368/perl-find-and-replace-specific-string-in-multiple-text-file) or [page2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774499/apply-multiple-find-and-replace-regex-queries-on-multiple-txt-files-using-a-per) can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\[/{h;b};G;s/^(index=)power\n.*(messages|secure)\]$/\1secure/;P;d' file
```

This appends the first line of each stanza to every other line and using pattern matching, replaces `power` by `secure`.

Comment: the inputs.conf is in this dir 
deployment-apps# _GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf, _GWAS_np_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf so if run the script it say No such file or directory
 
deployment-apps# sed -E '/^\[/{h;b};G;s/^(index=)power\n.*(messages|secure)\]$/\1secure/;P;d' inputs.conf
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf 
_GWAS_pr_linux_t1/local/inputs.conf

Comment: so the script has to match each stanza and change the index name to index=secure_np or secure_pr

Comment: Some of the index name endwith np and pr 
so the script has to match each stanza and change the index name to index=secure_np or secure_pr

Comment: @user10965163 please amend the question to show before and after states (also include all edge cases), I find it very difficult to understand from your comments.